# How to access the register value of find command in a loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I wanted to check the read permission of other group for all the files under /tmp/ap/*/jets/*/conf/.
When I do debug of find_config I am able to see the values of roth. But please let me know how to print those values alone.

```yaml
 - name: List config   
    shell: ls -d /tmp/ap/*/jets/*/conf/
    register: config
  - name: Status
    find:
      paths: "{{item}}"
    loop: "{{config.stdout_lines}}"
    register: find_config
  - debug:
     msg: "{{item.files.roth}}"
    loop: "{{find_config.results}}"
```

I also need to do a check like when roth is true then print FAIL.
I need something like below:

```yaml
  - debug:
     msg: "FAIL"
    when: item.files.roth
    loop: "{{find_config.results}}"
```

Part of the Debug output of find_config:

```
   "files": [
        {
            "atime": 1608008199.489219, 
            "ctime": 1608008199.4442186, 
            "dev": 624768, 
            "gid": 103, 
            "gr_name": "prt", 
            "isgid": false, 
            "islnk": false, 
            "isreg": true, 
            "issock": false, 
            "isuid": false, 
            "mode": "0640", 
            "mtime": 16008199.4442186, 
            "nlink": 1, 
            "path": "/tmp/ap/new1/jets/f2/conf/conf.xml", 
            "pw_name": "wl", 
            "rgrp": true, 
            "roth": false, 
            "rusr": true, 
            "size": 21835,
```

Comment: Pardon my stupid question, but what is `roth` refering to and what values does it contain? An example debug dump (partial if too big) of your registered variable would help

Comment: @Zeitounator, I have added the debug output. roth is the read permission of others. rwxrwx--- means others doesnt have read permsions.

Comment: @Vladmir, I do not know the exact path that needs to be put into find. I just know /tmp/ap/*/jets/*/conf/. I guess find module paths doesnt support wild cards.

Comment: @Smily a brilliant demonstration we can learn every day, and that we filter the info we see in our daily debugs (I had never notice that return value which is not clearly documented in on the module page). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I passed the output from shell to the paths in find and it is working now.

```
 - name: List config   
    shell: ls -d /tmp/ap/*/jets/*/conf/
    register: config
  - name: Status
    find:
      paths: "{{config.stdout_lines}}"
    register: find_config
  - debug:
     msg: "{{item.roth}}"
    loop: "{{find_config.files}}"
```